# VoIP-SIP : how to test VoiceMail system with sipp tool

Tags: xml, scripting, asterisk, sip

I'm developing a new application to test the good configuration of my voip server (asterisk).
The principle is to use sipp tool as a sip client in order to simulate several scénarios (simple call, call transfer, etc).
I want to test also the voicemail application configured and enabled in my voip server i.e : calling the voicemail by a sip client to perform many possible actions for example consult voicemails messages, erase them, listen to archived messages, etc.
this interaction between sip client an voicemail is based on dtmf codes assigned for every menu on the voicemail.
I'am asking if someone has an idea or an example about how to test/troubleshoot voicemail using sipp client :
-xml scénario to call voicemail and navigate between menus 
-how to send correct dtmf digit (1-9 or #) as rtp packets
-how to interpret correctly the voicemail menu invitation (how to convert rtp packets representing the menu option as an audio file or something similar)

I would really appreciate any expert or voip developer help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your Asterisk server to accept DTMF via SIP INFO requests. You will be able to send DTMF tones from sipp by manually constructing the SIP INFO requests.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback sipwiz. My server is configured to use DTMF RFC2833. So is there any possibility to use sipp to work with such configuration and test voicemail? if not, is there any similar tool providing this feature?

Comment: Maybe you could record the DTMF you need to send in separate audio files and get sipp to play those as part of the scenario once the call is set up. It would be a lot easier to change the DTMF setting on the Asterisk end though since it's only one line in the SIP config file..

Comment: OK it's clear sipwiz. by the way, I'm wondering if there any way to convert g729 packets (when the voicemail server plays a menu) into text file so I can validate if the server plays the good messages or not.

Comment: It would be possible to record the incoming RTP (if sipp can't do it you could use wireshark or tcpdump) and then convert it to PCM somehow and then do some voice recognition processing on it. That would be a lot of work and it sounds like overkill for testing a voicemail server. Personally I'd stick to checking that the vm server is answering calls, generating the correct SIP response, to check it's configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use same asterisk server for test itself

Use cmd_originate to do call

After that via dialplan send dtmf you want,record answer, convert answer via google speach to text or other service.

You can control dialplan using fastagi script if your testing plan is complex.

Also you can run second asterisk on other port on same machine and use it as originator.

Using sipp for that is very tricky.